# I can't install open ni on Indigo, what Linux version should I install instead

Tags: ros, kinect, linux, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What Linux version would be better to install if I want to use the Kinect?
electric,fuerte or hydro or what else?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197957/i-can%27t-install-open-ni-on-indigo,-what-linux-version-should-i-install-instead/) by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-22**:
You should be able to install openni on Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo. Can you be more specific about why you can't install openni and the EXACT error message that you're encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The openni_kinect stack is deprecated, and is no longer supported or released (as per the [openni_kinect wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_kinect) )

Instead, you should be using the openni_launch package: http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1